# Unable to access FileSystem of Azure Data Lake Gen2 with Angular using azure-sdk-for-js

Tags: angular, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal, azure-data-lake-gen2

I am developing an application with **Angular 8** and trying to connect to [Azure Data Lake Gen 2's FileSystem](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/azure/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-introduction) through its [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/data-lake-storage-gen2) in order to be able to retrieve the list of folders as well as do a file import.

For authentication I use the library [msal-angular](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/tree/dev/lib/msal-angular) that allows me to retrieve an **ID token** via the `loginPopup` function and an **access token** via `acquireTokenSilent` function.

I am using this scheme as a guide: [aad connection flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3DZgv.png)

The scope : `['user.read','api://<uuid>/user_impersonation']`. [api scopes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n4cmb.png)

Then I use the [storage-datalake](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/tree/master/sdk/storage/storage-datalake) library to try to retrieve information from my Data Lake. So I use the **access token** of my user logged to create a `DataLakeStorageClient` with `TokenCredentials`. Then I try to recover the list of folders on one of my FileSystems.

I'm getting this error: `401 (Server failed to authenticate the request. Please refer to the information in the www-authenticate header.)`.

> Do you have any idea where my problem might come from?

**My user has the following roles:**

- Contributor
- Storage Blob Data Contributor

**API permissions :** [api permissions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FyQ9u.png)

When I'm using [END-USER authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-store/data-lake-store-end-user-authenticate-rest-api) without **user impersonation** (as a service principal) I can access my filesystem...

*Thank you in advance for your help.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scope is not correct. You can not use two kinds of resource in the scope. `user.read` is for `https://graph.microsoft.com` resource. `api://<uuid>/user_impersonation` is for your own resource.

You can try with `['https://datalake.azure.net/.default']` as the scope.